# what to consider when chosing a UTP CAT6 brand

Tags: cat6, utp

What are the most important certifications to consider, when looking for brands of UTP to cable a building. (racks, vertical cabling, horizontal cabling). Im trying to find good quality at a decent price, and there seems to be lots of competitors in the market. I´m looking at Legrand, Siemon, 3M, AMP, Leviton.

Thanks,

Comment: Why not CAT5e instead of CAT6?

Comment: So we dont have to replace cabling in a few years time.

Comment: @Joe, I'm hoping he meant Cat6a, which can do 10GbE to 100m. Cat6 can do 10GbE, but only for short runs. Otherwise you're right, there's *very* little reason to use Cat6 over Cat5e.

Comment: Im looking at Cat6 (1GbE up to 100m) for the horizontal cabling.

Comment: Cat5e will carry 1GBe up to 100 meters (as will Cat5). Cat6a will carry 10GBe up to 100 meters so I'm hard pressed to see where Cat6 is a valid installation in any scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Cat6 is Cat6, if it meets the spec, it's good. The requirements of your local laws, commonly fire code in particular, usually up the requirement. Cables running through plenum spaces (above drop ceiling in offices) have to be fire retardant for instance. There could be a million different laws that we'd be completely unaware of. They're your responsibility to follow, or you can sub it out to a contractor...

Comment: +1 for comments about local legal laws and fire codes.  Running cable inside a building can also require a general contractor's license or a low voltage electrician license.

Comment: So who certifies that a brand of cable meets the spec?

Comment: It's a bit of self regulation. The manufacturer tests their own products using [TIA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telecommunications_Industry_Association) standard procedures. To produce a cable and call it certified requires a licensing agreement from them. If you're products are found to not meet the spec lawsuits, huge fines, injunctions (so you can't produce more) ensue. Their competitors would be more than happy to report any of the products failing to meet the standards. As for plenum and fire ratings, UL test and certifies the product, and it's a similar agreement.